# How to update R in Rstudio anaconda

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio

R in terminal  (3.5.1) -i use Linux- is not the same version on RStudio Anaconda (3.5.0).

RStudio 1.1.456 is update.

```
> install.packages('devtools')
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘devtools’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
```

So i can't use the updateR()

Comment: Check your network connection and could you please rephrase the question. It sounds difficult to understand what you're intending. As for my understanding goes, you're not able to install `devtools` package. Am I right?